# Stuck on emulator screen in Eclipse with Android Development?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've followed this tutorial: http://anandhansubbiah.com/blog/writing-your-first-android-application/, but no matter what I do, and what I change, when I run the app, all I see is the image below. Is there something I must press to start developing? Did I add starting code. I'm completely stumped...

[Screen I see http://img196.imageshack.us/img196/1700/stuckl.jpg](http://img196.imageshack.us/img196/1700/stuckl.jpg)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From you're screenshot it appears the emulator hasn't fully started so it's unlikely to be a problem with your app. It can take a while to start so leave it for a few minutes just to be sure it's not slow. If that doesn't work try recreating the AVD.

Once the AVD is running you can redeploy your app to it as often as you want so there's no need restart it.

Comment: Make also sure, that you have the latest SDK updates. The new updates and the 2.1 emulator works lot better than 1.6

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to press anything, and your code shouldn't be able to cause that. It looks like something's wrong with your emulator.

The SDK comes with a few tools you can use to try and figure out what's going on and fix it.

`adb` is the debug bridge - use `adb logcat` to see logs from the device. I don't think it will connect with the emulator in that state, but you might as well give it a try anyway.

`android` is the main AVD manager, and you can use it to create new virtual devices and see details if they failed to load.

If neither produce anything useful or obviously wrong with your virtual device, you might want to try just creating a new AVD in the manager and using that instead. You may also want to try starting the emulator yourself instead of letting Eclipse do it, just in case it's doing something to break it. Use the `emulator` tool in the SDK to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problems on a ee pc, it took half an hour to begin working, then i tried in a stronger pc and it works, Your pc may be to weak for the emulator, just think that the new phones have a 1400 MHz processor and they are running the program not the emulator which is much easier

Answer (score 1):

simply lower the ram in the edit menu and it should work fine

Answer (score 1):

When I start AVD, I enabled "Wipe User Data".

Answer (score 1):

When the AVD is created a folder /.android is created to store the AVD. I moved the folder. Restarted Eclipse and recreated the AVD and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Stop the emulator --> Open ADV Manager --> Edit the Virtual device --> Click Show Advanced Settings --> Set the Ram size 512mb --> Start the emulator